# IE8 is detecting the pages as mobile media

Tags: theming, media

I am trying to workout why http://www.tradecarsspain.com/ is loading as a mobile page when viewed in IE8 ...

Comment: Which module are you using for detecting mobile device? Or the logic?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for IE 8 or for module that is used to detect mobile browsers. Please report to appropriate issue queue instead.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't provided any information this is a complete guess, based on the assumption that you're using the [Omega 3](https://drupal.org/project/omega) theme with respond.js.

There's a [known issue](https://drupal.org/node/1388898) with IE8, respond.js and CSS aggregation. To fix it, you can implement `hook_css_alter()` in your theme like so:

```
function MYTHEME_css_alter(&$css) {
  // Enable respond.js to work with Omega.
  foreach ($css as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^ie::(\S*)/', $key)) {
      unset($css[$key]);
    }
    else {
      $css[$key]['browsers']['IE'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```